# More default named port in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

In kubernetes, I always see the service's definition like this:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: random-exporter
  labels:
    app: random-exporter
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: random-exporter
  ports:
    - port: 9800
      targetPort: http
      name: random-port
```

whose targetPort is `http`, it's human friendly！

And what I'm interested is that is there more named port such as `http` in kubernetes? Maybe `https`？

Comment: you may define any port  name you like in the pod spec and refer to it in the service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you refer to target port by its number. 
But you can give a specific name to each pod`s port 
and refer this name in your service specification.

This will make your service clearer.
Here you have example where you named your ports in pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    ports:
    - name: http
      containerPort: 8080
    - name: https
      containerPort: 8443
```

And here you refer to those ports by name in the service yaml.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-svc
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: https
```

Also from the [kubernetes documention](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#serviceport-v1-core) you may find this information:

`targetPort` - Number or name of the port to access on the pods targeted by the service. Number must be in the range 1 to 65535. Name must be an IANA_SVC_NAME. 
If this is a string, it will be looked up as a named port in the target Pod's container ports.

Comment: Thks. Yes, i realize that i make a misunderstand here. The named port is from pod's definition.